# Can't login to Instagram using Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, instagram

I'm trying to build a client-side application that allows people to login with their Instagram accounts. Problem is, I'm not sure if that's still possible.

I've coded a sample JavaScript after reading "Client-Side (Implicit) Authentication" section of their [related docs](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

I'm getting the following error:

```
{
"code": 400,
"error_type": "OAuthException",
"error_message": "JS login temporarily disabled"
}
```

From the error message I'm guessing it's not about my code but it's something on Instagram's side. Is there a way for me to do client-side login? Also, if I can't, what are my options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had similar issue and this is how I fixed it.

You have to uncheck the "**Disable implicit OAuth:**" by going to :

**->** Manage Clients

**->** Click edit on the app/webapp.

**->** **Uncheck** - Disable implicit OAuth:

**->** Update the settings and try to run it again by going to the link :

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=token
```

In the link, replace the values that were provided to you and in the **response_type**, give value as **token** to get the access token and if you want to get the **request code**, just replace **token** with the **code** in the URL.

Hope this helps for you and for future viewers.. Good luck.. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just unset the "Disable implicit OAuth:" in app settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems it's impossible to do JS login at the moment with Instagram.

But they still allow implicit redirects so the solution is to have a server to make a redirect to your client side application. You only need two endpoints. I've written a small Node.JS app for this which you can find [here](https://github.com/batuhan/InstaJS/blob/master/server/node/app.js).

Answer (score 0):

I had tried for the same,I think there are not still providing any api to login with Instagram credentials username and password,You can just authenticate your account via

https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code